# MVC4 Form Not Passing Object To Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to learn mvc and im making a simple social network to learn on.

This view displays a simple wall where you can add posts, add comments to posts, and delete posts.

I am having a problem trying to delete a post here and cant figure it out for the life of me. All i need to do is display a delete button for each post (this works ok), and then when they press delete send the extendedPostID to the controller action "Delete Post".

It is calling the action fine, but no data is being passed back to the controller. The more i try and fix this the more confused i get.

Could someone please take a look and give me some advice.

Thanks in advance.

VIEW

```
    @model IEnumerable<Q001.Models.PostExtended>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.Partial("_addNewPost", new Q001.Models.Post())

THIS IS THE END OF THE PARTIAL


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.post.UserID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.post.WallID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.post.PostDateTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.post.PostContent)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {        

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.post.UserID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.post.WallID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.post.PostDateTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.post.PostContent)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
                </td>          

            <td>
                @foreach (var comment in item.CommentExtended)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Comment.CommentContent)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Comment.CommentDateTime)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.FirstName)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Surname)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Username)
                }

                @Html.Partial("_addNewComment", new Quitzz001.Models.Comment() { PostID = item.post.PostID })
            </td>


            }
            <td>        
                @using (Html.BeginForm("DeletePost", "PostExtended"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(PostExtendedID => item.PostExtendedID)
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                }

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete Post", "DeletePost", new { id = item.post.PostID })
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.post.PostID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.post.PostID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.post.PostID })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
```

Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeletePost(Int32 item_PostExtendedID)
    {
     //delete post
    }
```

EDIT:

I have updated the code above as per the answers below.I have checked the html source and the hidden field seems to be populated.

the error i am getting is

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'PostExtendedID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeletePost(Int32)' in 'Q001.Controllers.PostExtendedController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter
```

This is the hidden field of one of the html forms

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PostExtendedID must be a number." data-val-required="The PostExtendedID field is required." id="item_PostExtendedID" name="item.PostExtendedID" type="hidden" value="3">
```

However i notice the id is item_PostExtendedID instead of PostExtendedID. (i tried changing variable name in my controller to item_PostExtendedID still with no luck).

Could this be the issue?

Comment: Not a fix to your problem: Since the name of the action method is DeletePost, you don't need to specify it again with the `ActionMethod` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

All you are passing into the action method is PostExtendedId. Update your action method signature:

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(int PostExtendedID)
```

Comment: Thank for your time, your explanation makes sense. however i am getting the error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'PostExtendedID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeletePost(Int32)' in 'Q001.Controllers.PostExtendedController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. with your modifications

Comment: That is because, the action method is not receiving `int PostExtendedId`. The value is not being passed in or the name is not a match. Use the developer tools in your browser to see what is actually being passed in

Comment: the field is there and seems to be populated. <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PostExtendedID must be a number." data-val-required="The PostExtendedID field is required." id="item_PostExtendedID" name="item.PostExtendedID" type="hidden" value="3">

Comment: i have updated my code above to show you what i have got at the moment

Answer (score 1):

The form you are submitting is passing an id

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PostExtendedID)
```

and the action you are posting to takes an object of type PostExtended

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(PostExtended PostExtended)
```

Unless you have created a custom model binder for PostExtended, then there's no way that MVC can automatically bind this for you. You would need to change your action to take an int with the same name as the element in the form (PostExtendedID)

(I'm assuming the ID is an int, obviously make it a string if it's a string)

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(int PostExtendedID)
{
//now you can use the id to do what you need to do    

}
```

Comment: Thank for your time, the explanation makes sense however i am getting the error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'PostExtendedID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeletePost(Int32)' in 'Q001.Controllers.PostExtendedController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. with your modifications

Comment: View source on the form that you are submitting. Check that there is a hidden field with an id that matches the parameter on your action (ie. PostExtendedID) and that it has a numerical value.

Comment: The feild is there and seems to be populated: <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PostExtendedID must be a number." data-val-required="The PostExtendedID field is required." id="item_PostExtendedID" name="item.PostExtendedID" type="hidden" value="3">

Comment: i have updated my code above to show you what i have got at the moment

Comment: Ah yes, the parameter name on the action should have item_ on the front. Needs to match the element id

Comment: Thank you for all your time but it is still giving me the same error. My action has an int called item_PostExtendedID and my view has @Html.HiddenFor(PostExtendedID => item.PostExtendedID)

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Post", "DeletePost", new { id = item.post.PostID })
```

It looks for a parameter named `id` in your action. If your PostExtended model doesn't have an `id` property, either rename it in your view to match your model, or simply write your action like this :

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(int id)
{
   // Delete The Post
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was from a previous attempt, i am not using that action link anymore and forgot to remove it from my code before submitting.